# Power consumption related to cache hit rate

Tags: power, computer-architecture, cache

Studying computer science engineering, I came across this question:

> We place an L0 cache in front of an L1 cache (so a fraction of the
>   cache accesses are serviced by the L0 cache instead of the L1 cache), this creates an opportunity to save power. What should be the minimum hit rate in the L0 cache for this organization to save power? (Assume *f* is the hit rate in L0, and *X* and *Y* is the power consumed per access to the L0 and L1 cache, respectively.)

I think it has something to do with the power formula we saw:

\$P = \frac{1}{2} C V^2 a f + I_{LC} V + I_{SC} V\$

But I have honestly no idea how I can relate the cache hit ratio to this. Thank you!

Comment: You have not put enough thought on this. All the data was given to you, X and Y, you don't need a formula for the power.

Comment: The question says: "X" is L0 cache power, "Y" is L1 cache power, "f" is the L0 hit rate, what's the average power in terms of X, Y and f? I'll give you a hint, your equation has a (1-f) term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you use that formula.

Just figure out the power savings from including the L0.

You have some situations (L0 hit - no L1 access; L0 miss - L1 access) compared to original (L1 access).

Since L0 is not free from a power standpoint, you have to have some balance point where adding the L0 in gives you a benefit.  As an extreme example if L0 missed 100% of the time, it would offer no additional power savings benefit and would actually increase the power by (X+Y)/Y %-age (as well as make the timing worse)

Comment: I was referring to that formula because I found some articles about cache hit rate having an effect on the leakage power. If I just think about it, I should solve the equation \$ fX + (1-f)(X+Y) < Y \$ to \$ f \$?

Comment: @TheJsp: I think leakage power is meant to be ignored in this example.